# Apple Pre-Release app submission "Missing beta entitlement"

Tags: ios, xcode6, ipa, itunes-store, code-signing-entitlements

I was trying a long to give pre-release thru itunes connect, I have created the new Certificate for production / App Id / Adhoc provisional profile against newly created certificate. I was always met with missing beta entitlement during export build thru organizer.

I had tried with Application Loader to send the build to itunes but received warning as below.

"Missing beta entitlement.Your app does not include the beta-reports-active entitlement. If you intend to distribute this build via TestFlight for beta testing, please re-build this app with a newly generated provisioning profile."

Adding Entitlement.plist file was not worked out,

[image]

This issue swallowed my whole day, If anyone produce right solution here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try using 'App Store Distribution Profile' instead of Ad-hoc. It will be still in pre-release state. You can add internal testers etc. This worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment let me check it out and let you know. before that, I have push notification enabled for my app. if the build comes under app store distribution profile then would people get notify to their devices? since we were not forced to choose option to select any devices during profile (app store profile) creation. please advice.

Comment: The people who are in your internal testers list, those devices will get notified only.

Comment: Oh! ok, then what about external testers, mostly the distributions would be goes to external testers who are referred by owner of the app.

Comment: Everyone then, so now  are u able to upload pre-release version?

Comment: Not yet implemented, I'll do and let you know. thanks for your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 known options :

1 - edit your .plist file and add "beta-reports-active" line like below (Value must be true) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>beta-reports-active</key>
        <true/>
        <key>application-identifer</key>
        <string>youridentifierhere</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

2 - If didn't work, for some cases "create brand new provision profile" could work.

Comment: I have created everything as new as I commented, even certificate / app id but still no luck. Can you list me the procedure to create and add plist in my target?

Comment: Probably you have your plist under "Supporting Files"? And just add this line after that...

Comment: Setting the key `beta-reports-active` to 'true' did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

This got screwed up by Apple when they merged TestFlight into iTunes Connect.  I'm assuming that you have an old certificate still.  You need to regenerate your certificates and provisioning profiles and go through the signing process from the beginning.

Comment: Nope, I had created my new certificate today morning and done all above stuffs, still I don't know why this happening.